# Difference between `FindOneBy` and `Find` in Doctrine

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

With Doctrine it is possible to find by a ID, like if you want to have all the information about a user.

You can do it like this:
**$em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(array('id' => 1));**

Or you can do this:
**$em->getRepository(User::class)->find(1);**

Both give the same result, but for FindOneBy you can define a array.

What if you want to search on a ID only, what is better? and why is it better (maby for the performance)?

Comment: I think `findOneBy` is useful when you want to find a result based on multiple conditions. Whereas `find` is useful for finding a result based only on an `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With findOneBy you can make:

```
->findOneBy(['id' => 1, 'enabled' => true], ['createdAt' => 'DESC']);
```

Otherwise find is prefer way to work without db query.

For example:

```
$swag = new Swag();
$swag->setSwagLevel(42);
$this->em->persist($swag); // Now you entity inside persistent collection, not in db.

$swag = $this->em->find(Swag::class, $swag->getId()) // Return entity from persistent collection, not from db in that case. Dump this $this->em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions()


$user->giveSwag($swag);

$this->em->flush(); // Store all chain of changes to db.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And if you use find(..) like in your example, will it be better for load time or something?

I asked this because I'm in a discussion with a student who always use findOneBy but I prefer find also if I'm going to search on a ID only.

Comment: There wont be a big difference in execution time of both.